# How can I get this HTTPS picture by Java?

Tags: java, http, web-crawler

https://t.williamgates.net/image-E026_55A0B5BB.jpg

I tried `HttpURLConnection` and `HttpsURLConnection`, always got this exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
```

Anyone can help for this issue? show me some codes if you can, thanks!

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @DanPantry Thanks for comment, my code may useless for this question, just google it "HttpsURLConnection example", and it worked for `https://www.google.com` but not for `https://t.williamgates.net/image-E026_55A0B5BB.jpg`

Comment: @Zenofo but may be you need to post your code .i just try it i'm not getting that error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need..

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ReadImages {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://t.williamgates.net/image-E026_55A0B5BB.jpg").openStream());
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("image.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReadImages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

You should refer the following classes

1. [`java.awt.image.BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)
2. [`javax.imageio.ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)
3. [`java.net.URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this for any files, not just images:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class DownloadFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("https://t.williamgates.net/image-E026_55A0B5BB.jpg").openStream());
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("img.jpg")));

        int data;
        while((data = in.read()) != -1){
            out.write(data);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();       
    }
}
```

You can make it more faster, when you use the in.read(byte b[], int off, int len) method instead of in.read(). Just google it for some examples.